# Is there a way to print SEL action?

Tags: objective-c, ios, selector

For example, I want to trace the actions sent to my canPeformAction and they are too numerous to display at each occurrence with a "hover" in the debugger.  Therefore, I want to trace to the log and examine it after my test cycle.

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"%s: sender=%@", __FUNCTION__, sender, action);
}
```

Comment: I found my answer: NSStringFromSelector(action)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You want

```
NSLog(@"%s: sender=%@, selector=%s", __FUNCTION__, sender,sel_getName(action));
```

Comment: `sel_getName()` returns a C string, not an `NSString`. Use `%s` for the format or (better) `NSStringFromSelector()`.

Comment: Thanks Jacques and Dave - I found the macro NSStringFromSelector after I asked the question.  +1 and accept to you.

Answer (score 12):

Use **NSStringFromSelector** to easily get a printable name of the Selector.

`NSStringFromSelector(action)`

> `NSString * NSStringFromSelector ( SEL aSelector );`
>
> Returns a string representation of a given selector.

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Action: %@", NSStringFromSelector(action));
}
```